# Where does project.json file look for packages?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, project.json

Where does project.json file look for packages on msbuild event?

Can we control the search tree?

Comment: I'm confused, what kind of msbuild event are you talking about? And why are you talking about a tree? Maybe it would help if explained what is it you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: The MSBuild event is the build! When I build the class library project I have the packages restore that are listed in project.json but they do NOT copy to the BIN folder. I want to know where the build looks for packages when using project.json.  With package.config I would just look at the hintpath in the csproj file.  There IS no reference in the csproj file when using project.json, so how to confirm msbuild is looking in the right place for the packages assemblies?

Comment: Did you try running a diagnostic msbuild? `msbuild /v:diag > build.log`. Then you can see where the assembly references are being taken from. They should be from your packages directory under your user's profile.